# Elementary Differential Equations - What am I doing wrong in this exercise?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to do exercise 19, chapter 2.1, of the book on elementary differential equations from Boyce and DiPrima.  Basically to solve:
$t^{3} y' + 4 t^{2} y = e^{-t}, \quad   y(-1)=0, \quad t<0$.
I try to solve this problem in the following way:

1). Since $t \neq 0$, then the above equation can be written as $y' + \frac{4}{t}y = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{3}}$.

2). Multiply the above equation by an integrating factor $\mu(t)$:  $\mu(t) y' + \mu(t) \frac{4}{t} y = \mu(t) \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{3}}.$

3). Find $\mu(t)$ such that the left side satisfies: $\frac{d}{dt}(\mu(t) y) = \mu(t) y' + \mu(t) \frac{4}{t} $.  Hence $\frac{d \mu(t)}{dt} = \mu(t) \frac{4}{t}$.  Assuming $\mu(t)>0$, and after solving this differential equation, I reach that $\mu(t) = t^{4}$.

4). My original diff. equation becomes: $\frac{d}{dt}\left( t^{4} y \right) = t e^{-t}$ and hence $y(t) = \frac{1}{t^{4}} \left( \int_{t}^{0}s e^{-s}ds + c \right)$, for some constant $c$.  I took the limit of integration between $t$ and $0$ since $t<0$.

5). I solve by parts the integral $\int_{t}^{0}s e^{-s}ds = e^{-t}(1+t)-1$.  In order to satisfy the initial condition, $c=1$.

6).  My solution becomes $y = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{4}} \left( 1 + t \right)$, which is not exactly the solution given in the book.  There the solution is just as mine, but with an additional negative sign, i.e. $y = - \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{4}} \left( 1 + t \right)$.

Can someone please shed some light where I might have missed this negative sign?  Given that $t<0$, should I have taken extra considerations in the above example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly apply the fundamental theorem, as the derivative of
$$
\int_t^0f(s)ds=F(0)-F(t)
$$
is $-F'(t)=-f(t)$. Thus in your formula for $y$ you have to use $-\int_t^0f(s)ds$, thus the extra minus sign. That is, changing the orientation of the integration changes the sign of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

To make the calculations easier, don't put the limits of integration in!

We have $$t^4y=\int te^{-t}\,dt=-te^{-t}-e^{-t}+C=-(1+t)e^{-t}+C$$ where $C$ is a constant.

As $y(-1)=0$, $$(-1)^4\cdot0=-(1+(-1))e^{-1}+C\implies C=0$$ so $$\boxed{y=-\frac{e^{-t}}{t^4}(1+t)}$$ as required.